# sigma notation without elements and upper bound

Tags: summation, notation, algorithms

I am implementing the algorithms found in the pdf document downloadable at this link [An Effective Simulated Annealing Algorithm for Solving the Traveling Salesman Problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233584468_An_Effective_Simulated_Annealing_Algorithm_for_Solving_the_Traveling_Salesman_Problem).

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the summation found at the very end of the first column on page 4 of the pdf (step 3 of the second stage of the algorithm).

I have no real mathematical background but, as far as I can understand, the upper bound can be assumed to be the number of cities (excluded the one randomly chosen).
I'm also assuming that the lack of elements to sum in the formula defaults to 1 (one), meaning that the result of the summation is nothing more than a mere count of the cities (minus one; the x1 randomly extracted).

Am I correct? If yes I wonder why not to write a simple n-1?

I hope is clear where my bafflement come from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no summation on page for, nor do I see summations without indexes...

Comment: You are probably reading it directly from the web page. In this case is on page 3.

Comment: The fourth page in the scan I can see behind the link is page 1683. and there is no summation in either of the columns there.

Comment: page 1682. step 3 of the second stage of the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I think.

I don't know if it is common practice in a mathematical grammatic sense, but it seems to me that the denominator in formula(8) is not a "real" summation.

Anyway the meaning of that sigma, as far as I can understand, should be: sum all the roads distances excluding the ones leading to or departing from city x1.

In other words "eliminate" the city x1 from the map, then sum all the remaining roads lengths.

It makes sense, algorithmically speaking, I think.

Let me know if you see some flaw in my thought.

Answer (score 0):

I can't restore the meaning to this summation, that is missing a summand. All symptoms of a typo.